# How do I make my discord bot send a message in channel y regardless of which channel the command was sent in

Tags: python, discord.py

I tried to use `if ctx.channel=='name-of-channel': #blah blah'` but im not quite sure why it doesnt work at all? The attempt there was to make the bot send the message if the command was sent in the 'name-of-channel'.

I dont want to do it with the channel id though, because if someone deletes the channel and recreates it with the same name, i want the command to still work. Bonus points would be if I could make the bot send the message in the channel y even if the command was given in channel x. Thank you everyone!

Comment: If you're confused as to why this is a duplicate of that other question, it's because one of the answers to that question explains how to get a channel by name.

Comment: Yes sir! @RandomDavis I fixed it and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked, this being closed as a duplicate is a reminder that you should search for the issue before asking a question, since with something as simple as this someone has surely asked this before.